# Creating different PendingIntent objects - request code vs. different Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

In my code, i am creating various PendingIntent objects using getBroadcast().

My application needs to represent a few different types of PendingIntents, and for this reason i create the underlying Intent with a different action string (unique per PendingIntent).

My question is - does it make any difference to differentiate the pending intents by the request code, or stick with the technique i am doing now ?

Example:

What i'm doing now:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Receiver.class);
intent.setAction("unique.name.here");

PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, flags);
```

Other technique:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Receiver.class);
PendingIntnt.getBroadcast(this, uniqueId, intent, flags);
```

Is there any reason why should i pick one technique over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use whatever technique you want that works for you. Sometimes you need a unique `PendingIntent` but you can't use a unique action because the action is used for some other purpose (Intent resolution or whatever).

Comment: For matching Intent objecs,do i get back the same object instance when calling getBroadcast() ?

Comment: No, you don't get back the same object instance. But you get back an object that maps to the same `PendingIntent` "token". `PendingIntent` objects are stored in the `ActivityManager`, what you get back is basically a "token" that points to one of these. For matching `Intent`s, you get back the same "token".